# Angular web page with elements build from JSON or XML

Tags: javascript, html, json, xml, angular

So firstly, I'm new to WebDev. I've not made a website since I was in college 10 years ago, and that was using Dreamweaver...
So you might need to talk to me like an idiot and that's fine.

Is this possible?
I've got to make a single page web app that interacts with a database through a custom api. This API is currently being expanded daily as it's still being developed by others.

What I would like to do is create a website that has elements dynamically added depending on either a JSON or XML file. For example:

```
{
    "Migrate": {
        "_comment": "The Switch enables or disables the module",
        "Switch": "False",
        "Source": "True",
        "Destination": "True",
        "DB-Name": "True",
        "Port": "9200",
        "API-Call": "api/foo"
    },

    "Export": {
        "_comment": "This was a triumph",
        "Switch": "True",
        "Source": "True",
        "Destination": "False",
        "DB-Name": "True",
        "Port": "9200",
        "API-Call": "api/bar"
    }
}
```

This would create two potentially create two modules within the web app with Migrate and Export, however Migrate is switched to false, so it would with be greyed out or disabled entirely. Anything else that's labelled false isn't needed and would be hidden.

My goal is to make this easily expandable in the future, just by simply adding more lines into the json file.

Comment: `This would create two potentially create two modules within the web app`, what do u want them to do ? eg: Add a link named `Migrate` which opens a detail page and calls API endpoint at `api/foo` etc..

Comment: Sorry I didn't cover that. Basically, I want this to populate a navigation panel on the left of the page, then clicking on one of them will populate the main area with a form generated from the other options. Clicking submit then sends that to the api and executes it

Comment: Okay so there is a navigation panel with `Migrate`, `Export` etc.. But which are the other options that are supposed to generate the form ?

Comment: So if you look at the json, you'll see I've got fields such as source, destination and db-name. If these are set to "true", it'll include it in the form. It'll automatically build the form depending on the json.

Comment: What you are trying to create is basically a dynamic form and angular documentation has a [good example](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form). But be aware, Angular might not be the correct tool, if you want to quick solution, since it has a steep learning curve.

Comment: @s.alem, thanks for that link, not sure how I missed it. I know Angular has a steep learning curve but I'll get there. Sure version 1 wont be a work of art  but that's learning for you. Right now it's for internal usage only

Comment: @AlistairHardy You're welcome. Sure, if you want to learn some modern UI technologies, then you are on the right track. Angular and React are the major players in the game today.